# Visual Studio plugin to work with Google Docs

Tags: visual-studio, google-docs, visual-studio-extensions

I was hoping to find a plugin (or a way) to **Visual Studio 2008/2010** that captures real time changes in the current code file and apply it on a **Google Docs** online document.

That is because I need a way to illustrate & share code online in real time with others, and do not want to write outside my IDE without intellisense.

Does that addon/plugin exist?

Comment: Is this something you can accomplish with a screencast or some sort?

Comment: ...how about something like VNC or GoToMeeting?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question about Google Docs, but [VS Anywhere](http://www.vsanywhere.com/Default.aspx) might let you:

> illustrate & share code online in real time with others

and not force you to:

> write outside my IDE without intellisense

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool that works like this with Google Docs, but the the VS2010 extension [wave-vs.net](http://wave-vs.net) allows for real-time collaboration within Visual Studio.